# How do I save and retrieve form values including dropdowns using cookies?

Tags: javascript, forms, cookies, drop-down-menu

Is there an easy way to save forms just for people who accidentally click a link then use the back button or something? Including a dropdown input.

Answer (score 0):

You could do an `onkeypress` for input boxes and textarea, and `onchange` event on all selects in your form. and every triggered event, call a script that serializes your form into a JSON string and store them as a cookie. and if your form is submitted, you can clear that cookie after.

In the scenario that the user moved away from the page, you should bind an `onbeforeunload` or `onunload` to warn the user that he's moving away. if he confirms, clear the cookie. if somehow the confirmation is skipped, the next time he visits the form, just read the cookie since it was not cleared.

but also note that there is a possibility that sensitive data might be entered. cookies (and even localstorage) is not safe for storage. you could provide an expiration so that the cookie gets deleted if it's not refreshed.